# Access isolated scope in angular directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I am currently writing an angular directive that uses a template in a different HTML file and an isolated template. The directive gets some string via @ to its scope and that value is available in teh controller function.
Somehow its not available via {{}} in the HTML template. Why is that so? How can I change that? I read something about the template using the parent scope but I don't fully understand that.

Here is a code example:

```
angular.module('moduleName')

.directive('aGreatDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            mapid: '@'
        }, 
        templateUrl: "path/to/template.html",

        controller: ['$scope', function (scope) {
            console.log($scope.mapid); // is defined
       }
    }
});
```

And the html code for the template:

```
<div id="{{mapid}}"></div>
```

The result in the browser is exactly the same where it should be:

```
<div id="theValueOfmapid"></div>
```

Thanks for your help!

PS Here is a jsfiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22032/)

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I just did. {{mapid}} should be thisisthemapid in the output, but it isn't. The console statements are also strange. In my console I see the mapid attribute, but $scope.mapid is undefined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle was incorrect since you didn't have your controller defined or $scope injected properly.  The following will work just fine:

template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a-great-directive mapid="thisisthemapid"></a-great-directive>
    Some other code
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function () {
});

myApp.directive('aGreatDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            mapid: '@'
        },
        template: "<div id='{{mapid}}'> {{mapid}} </div>",
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.mapid); // is defined
        }
    ]}
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhwuzqse/)

Note that in my example, the injected variable in your directive's controller should be `$scope`, not `scope`, for consistency reasons.

Comment: Thanks that example works! Do you by any chance have an idea where the error in my real app is? I am using a similar setup and with an empty controller (of the directive) everything works. The moment I copy some cesium code and a dependency to angular cesium into the controller this code gets executed but the templates {{mapid}} doesn't get replaced. What could I do to find the error?

Comment: Start with the console and see if you get any errors there.  That's always going to be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks. The only errors I get are from that code inside. The code can't find an element because the id is not set to mapid. If I set that id by hand I don't get any errors at all. Very strange.

Comment: Then you have a race condition where your code is looking for the id before the directive is run.  If that's the case, it sounds like you're taking an anti-angulary approach to begin with since you shouldn't be driving activity off of IDs in the DOM

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am using non angular code here but isn't a directive the right way to include that code? Is there an (easy) way to let that code run only after the directive did its job replacing?

Comment: You'd need to invoke the code from your directive in that case and trigger appropriate digest cycles if necessary using $timeout.