# How to rerender part of html in directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have such a situation:

My directive delete some html blocks and stores it.
Here is the link function:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
  var storedHtml = angular.copy(angular.element(el)[0].innerHTML);
  angular.element(el)[0].innerHTML = '';

  $timeout(function() {
    angular.element(el)[0].innerHTML = storedHtml;
    scope.$apply();

  }, 5000);
}
```

I use my directive for example in `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div my-directive>
      <p>{{item.name}} </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So `storedHtml` could be like this:

```
<p>{{item.name}}</p>
```

Is there any possibility to rerender this part of html block, or at least whole ng-repeat block to update values?

Comment: what you want to render? `<p>{{item.name}}</p>` or `<p>Evaluated Value</p>`?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Second one <p>Evaluated Value</p>

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that, why not just pass the item into your directive and have the directive's template output what you want?

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div my-directive data="item"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your directive, you can access `item` using isolate scope (there are other directive scope methods that would work as well, but I prefer isolate).

Part of your directive would be:

```
scope: {
    data: '='
},
template: '<p>{{ data.name }}</p>'
```

You can also access any other properties from `item` here and return them to the view.

Comment: For reference on isolate scope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730412/access-isolated-scope-in-angular-directive-template